# ISerializable list items aren't deserialized with BinaryFormatter. C# Xamarin

Tags: c#, serialization, xamarin.android

I have an `ISerializable` class containing a list of `ISerializable` items from an abstract class, but the actual objects from the derived classes aren't `ISerializable`. Whenever I try to deserialize `ScheduledTasksController`, its constructor is called and `scheduledTasks` is deserialized correctly. However, the list's items are null and `ScheduledTask`'s constructor is not called, even though serialization works correctly. Any ideas on what I could be doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

Code below:

```
[Serializable]
public class ScheduledTasksController:ISerializable
{
    private List<ScheduledTask> scheduledTasks = new List<ScheduledTask>();

    public ScheduledTasksController(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
    {
        scheduledTasks = (List<ScheduledTask>)info.GetValue("tasks", typeof(List<ScheduledTask>));
    }

    public void GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
    {
        info.AddValue("tasks", scheduledTasks, typeof(List<ScheduledTask>));
    }
}

[Serializable]
public abstract class ScheduledTask:ISerializable
{
    public ScheduledTask(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
    {
        //code
    }

    public void GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
    {
        //code
    }
}

[Serializable]
public class RepeatingScheduledTask : ScheduledTask
{
    //code
}

[Serializable]
public class OneTimeScheduledTask : ScheduledTask
{
    //code
}
```

Comment: It is hard to give advice without seeing what `//code` is.

Answer (score 0):

You need to actually provide the Serialisation function (implement the Interface). Wich includes calling the serialsiation functions for all contained objects. Serialiseable Lists and Arrays do that by default. And the current advised ones all implement ISerialiseable properly.

The default (de-)serialisers can cover only all public fields. Anything more complex (private and even readonly properties) are beyond it.